# jQuery's slidedown() function deprecated?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my divs to slide down using `$('#theDiv').slideDown('fast');`

In the jQuery version I'm using, 3.2.1, I get a console error

`TypeError: $(...).slideDown is not a function`

Am I right that the function has been deprecated, and if so, why, and is there a replacement available?

It works when I use

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

but not

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Not deprecated and should work. 

Make sure that you spelled your ID #theDiv correctly. Not being able to find the DOM element to attach the jQuery object to will throw the same error.

Comment: @Korgrue I've updated my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not deprecated and should work.

You are using the slim version, which does not include the effects and ajax functions.

Use this one instead: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: Thanks! until I found your post, I kept thinking I had an error